# Difficulty Parsing JSON With Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I have this snippet of code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:10.3;20.7/?token=demo").responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }

        guard let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
            let data = JSON["data"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
                print("Could not parse weather values")
                return
        }
```

It seemed to be working a few days ago but now when I run the application it will print the Could not parse weather values indicating that it is not parsing the JSON data correctly. I've gone back and changed it to what it used to be but it seems to be broken still.

I'm hoping someone here will be able to help me out with this as it's a crucial component of my first project that will be published to the App Store.

EDIT: Just to add, it successfully prints the JSON data at the `print("JSON: \(JSON)")` line

Comment: Can you show us what is printed from `print("JSON: \(JSON)")`? I have a feeling I know what it is anyway, but it's always nice to see the JSON output..

Comment: It generally isn't advised to post duplicates, especially of your own questions. You should be able to go check your past questions to get the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need I post my response word for word from the last time you posted this question?

> You can parse your result following the printout of your JSON
>   response:
>
> ```
> guard let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
>     let weather = JSON["weather"] as? [[String:Any]] else {
>     print("Could not parse weather values")
>     return
> }
>
> for element in weather {
>     if let description = element["description"] as? String {
>         print(description)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you wanted to save the result, or do something based on a certain
>   result as you described, you could insert something else instead of
>   just `print(description)` like:
>
> ```
> if description == "sunny" {
>     //do something
> }
> ```
>
> Let me know if this makes sense. Keep in mind that `(` and `)` in the
>   Xcode console means "Array".

I really ought to be flagging this as a duplicate of [Save Alamofire Result as Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784855/save-alamofire-result-as-variable/41784952#41784952)

Edit: Based on this JSON snippet - http://pastebin.com/XiGhNA26 - it should be easy to parse out the desired information with:

```
guard let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
    let data = JSON["data"] as? [String:Any] else
{
    print("Could not parse weather values")
    return
}
```

The difference is that in this JSON response, the "data" parameter is not an array of dictionaries, it is just a dictionary itself.

Comment: Apologies, I should have posted it on the original post really, but here is the output from the console: http://pastebin.com/XiGhNA26 I used the original code you provided but tweaked the variable names to use with the new URL.

Comment: See the edit @Miles the reason for your issue is clear based on the JSON output

Comment: I thought that was the case I just couldn't figure out how to adapt the code, would I still be able to use

`for element in weather {
    if let description = element["description"] as? String {
        print(description)
    }
}`
to pull info from the data array or will I need to adapt this too?

Comment: No you won't be able to use that anymore. `data` is no longer an array, so this simple `for` loop won't work, and `"description"` doesn't exist in this JSON response. @Miles

Comment: Would `let idx = data["idx"] As Int` work to save the idx value into it's own variable as an integer?

Comment: You would need an optional cast, which results in type `Int?` not type `Int`. If I were you, I would just add another `let` onto the `guard` statement: `let idx = data["idx"] as? Int` @Miles

Comment: That works brilliantly, thank you for the help again. Apologies for the double post too.

Also once I've got a little more disposable income I will be in contact to donate to your Mealsloth project partly as a thank you and partly due to the fact I think it is a great idea!

Answer (score -1):

In you guard statement you are doing the same thing twice. That's not necessary. Take a look at this code and test it out. I'm not able to test your code right now, but I believe the error is around the area of where the downcasting happens. I believe improving that will help you.

```
Alamofire.request("https://api.waqi.info/feed/geo:10.3;20.7/?token=demo").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")

        let parsed = JSON as? NSDictionary //Here is your son data ready to be used
        //We can access the data content
        let data = parsed["data"] //The data is here and can be access using keys
        print("Data: \(parsed["data"])")
    }else{
       print("Values don't exists")
       return
    }

    }
```

Comment: It may be true that `response.result.value` is being unwrapped twice, but that is not the source of the issue and does not answer OP's question.